# Пересекающиеся vs. непересекающиеся вхождения в стороку

Tags: python, строки, методы

В контексте этого: "Метод count(, , ) считает количество непересекающихся вхождений подстроки  в исходную строку s". Какая разница?

Comment: сколько раз `xx` входит в строку `xxx`? если без пересечений, то один, а с пересечением — два.

Comment: Например, 'aaaaaaa'.count('aa') == 3, но вообще говоря существует 6 индексов i таких, что с них начинается подстрока 'aa'. То есть метод count начинает искать следующую подстроку строго после конца предыдущей, пропуская те моменты, когда эта подстрока могла начаться внутри другой подстроки.

Answer (score 2):

Возьмём строку "ConConConCon" и найдём вхождения в неё подстроки "ConCon".

Кол-во непересекающихся вхождений - два: **ConCon**ConCon и ConCon**ConCon**

Кол-во пересеккающихся вхождений - три: **ConCon**ConCon  Con**ConCon**Con  ConCon**ConCon**